# Universal .deb or .rpm

Tags: rpm, packaging, deb

I noticed that the download page for VSCode (https://code.visualstudio.com/download) has a single `.deb` for all versions of Ubuntu/Debian/etc. and a single `.rpm` for all versions of RE/Fedora/SUSE/etc.

How can a single file work for multiple versions of a single distro, let alone multiple distros? I would think that different versions of libraries etc. would make this not work, as seems clear from e.g. https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian or https://superuser.com/questions/1650570/is-it-safe-to-install-ubuntus-deb-packages-on-debian-are-deb-packages-univer

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind creating universal packaging formats is that they make packages easier to maintain.

All Debian-based distributions are based on the same .deb packaging format that is inherited from Debian. That is why the Visual Studio Code .deb package that Microsoft made works universally on all Debian-based  distributions. Instead of creating multiple .deb packages, one for each Debian-based distribution, Microsoft created one generic .deb package for all of them.

All rpm-based distributions are based on the same .rpm packaging format that is inherited from either Fedora or RHEL, and as a result the Visual Studio Code .rpm package that Microsoft made works universally on all rpm-based  distributions.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: As I suggested in the last paragraph, snap packaging is close as there is for a universal packaging format that supports both .deb and .rpm. Were you asking about something else? Do you think this answer deserves to be deleted?

Comment: I am asking specifically about a universal .deb (for all versions of Debian/Ubuntu/etc.) and a universal .rpm (for all versions of RH etc.) as seen on the VSCode download page. How can these exist and work correctly? I am not asking how to install VSCode using some kind of universal installer.

Comment: You can think of snap packaging as not a universal .deb or a universal .rpm but a  universal packaging format for both .deb and .rpm that is made possible by the fact the snap packages are packaged as standalone packages.

Comment: I know what a snap is. I am not asking how to do snaps. I am asking how Microsoft did a universal .deb. Please look at the page I linked to in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that when you statically link. I.e., you do not use system libraries. You have very minimal requirements. On the other hand, every time a security problem appears in these libraries, you must rebuild your package. Which people rarely do.